# Calculate difference between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

The title might be a bit misleading, but what I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY pid ASC
```

And in one of the columns I have a DATE(). I want to compare the current date (not time) and return how many days are left till that date. Let's say the date is `2013-04-20` and today's date is `2013-04-16` I don't want to get any data if it's `< current date`. If it is I want it returned in days.

I've been looking around here and I've found no way to do it, and I can't for the love of me figure it out.

Comment: What flavour of SQL server?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why did you post a misleading title?  You should have just posted a non-misleading title.

Comment: @djechlin: what's misleading about the title?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name first line says "The title might be a bit misleading."  It's not wrong, just vague.  I'm thinking of how to make it precise.

Comment: You can try, Convert(varchar,dateColumnName,101)>convert(varchar,getdate(),101)  If you are using MS sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the difference between two date you can use the GETDATE function in MS SQL

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, DateOne, DateTwo) FROM TABLE
```

This will return the difference in number of days between the two dates.

If you only want rows where the date field is less than or equal to today's date you can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, DateField, GETDATE())
FROM TableName
WHERE DateField <= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL you can use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_column) AS days_diff
FROM
    tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference between two dates (ANSI SQL)

```
select the_date_column - current_date as days_left
from the_table
where the_date_column - current_date <= 4;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3148d/1